# Getting PHP's `output buffering & flushing` work - expectedly

Tags: php, buffer, flush

The code below goes thru a large file and spits the line one by one...
but the darn thing just waits and waits and waits on this 6000-line-file -with a browser status message "transferring data from localhost..." - which eventually does!

I'm just curious what else to be done here to avoid the wait and see the instant results..

```
    //------------------------------------------------ 
    if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start(); 
    //------------------------------------------------

    echo '<pre><ol>';
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    while(!feof($handle)){
    $line = fgets($handle);
    echo '<li>' , $line , "\n";
    //------------------------------------------------
    ob_flush();
    flush();    
    //------------------------------------------------
    }
    echo '</pre>';
    fclose($handle);

    //------------------------------------------------
    ob_end_flush();
    //------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like the browser to respond immediately - as the server processes each iteration in the loop.

The desired result is that I should be able to see the document in the browser getting bigger and bigger while the vertical scroll bar is getting smaller and smaller in a constant fashion.

Comment: there is **NO** point in turning on the OB system, then flushing the buffer every iteration. just call `flush()`. and remember that even if PHP is flushing its buffers, you have NO control over what the overlying webserver is doing.

Comment: Why on earth are you not simply doing it with AJAX?

Comment: Marc, I tried that. Removed all the lines that's got ob_ in it. To be exact, I commented 3 lines in the originial script, leaving just the flush(). No difference.

Comment: Loz, this is all about why the flush() is not doing what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to load to screen why use ob_flush at all?  ob_flush processes everything before dumping it to screen. Why not dump it to screen from the beginning?

Comment: This should really be a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to comment :)

Comment: Doogie, either way, there is an unacceptable amount of delay. Before coming to PHP, I used to program in Classic ASP. If I do the same thing, and I use the flush's ASP equivalent, which is  Response.Flush, everything works the way you would want it to be.